# Are Disjoint Set Assertions Commutative?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I were to say that A intersect B was the empty set, does that imply that B intersect A is also the empty set?

Comment: How could this fail? (It is not a rhetorical question.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Because
$A \cap B = \{ x | x \in A \text{ and } x \in B \}$ and surely "and" is commutative.

Answer (score 0):

A ∩ B := {(x ∊ U)|(x ∊ A) ⋀ (x ∊ B)}
You can see that this is a logical statement of the form P ⋀ Q and any logic textbook will 
tell you that P ⋀ Q = Q ⋀ P, i.e. that ⋀ is commutative, that seems to me to be the 
justification.